# How to select node in dynatree

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, dynatree

```
tree.dynatree({
        initAjax: {
            url: "../Users/GetTree"
        },
        checkbox: true,
        selectMode: 2,
        fx: { height: "toggle", duration: 200 },
        persist: true,
        clickFolderMode: 1,
        autoFocus: false,

         onClick: function (node, event) {
           ....
         }
   }
```

on server side I have class TreeNode

```
 public class TreeNode
 { 
      .....

      public TreeItemsAttr attr { get; set; }

      public string addClass { get; set; }
 }
```

and class   TreeItemsAttr

```
 public class TreeItemsAttr
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public bool canHaveSubs { get; set; }

    public bool selectable { get; set; }

    public bool isSelected { get; set; }

    public string docDate { get; set; }
}
```

So, in my action I setup some tree node `isSelected=true` and add class `addClass="dynatree-selected"`, but when I call `node.tree.getSelectedNodes()` I get `[]`.

How can I setup on server side so the some nodes are selected?

I also try to add in TreeNode property select and setup to true, but it did not help me.

Answer (score 1):

In [dynatree document page](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/dynatree-doc.html) (In Section : 5.3 Handling selection events) there is a sample for that aim.

```
onSelect: function(flag, node) {
        if( ! flag )
            alert("You deselected node with title " + node.data.title);
        var selectedNodes = node.tree.getSelectedNodes();
        var selectedKeys = $.map(selectedNodes, function(node){
            return node.data.key;
        });
        alert("Selected keys: " + selectedKeys.join(", "));
    }
```

and the result page is : http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-select.html

This way is working in Client side, but i think you can send selected variables to your server.

Answer (score 1):

After you follow Alper's example, you can then save the selectedKeys to a hidden field, making those values available to you on the server side:

```
var arraySelKeys = selectedKeys.toString().split(",");
$("[id$=_hdnSelKeys]").val(arraySelKeys.toString());
```